# Custom language auto complete

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a new language within VS Code and am trying to build auto complete options (similar to Javascript). I have seen that the auto complete (intellisense) suggestions are taken from a file es6.d.ts which I have copied and modified to suit my language.

The language is almost the same as Javascript (as far as syntax goes), I just need to use this updated ts file with my language.

How would I go about setting up auto complete to work with my custom language and ts file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you checkout the lsp-sample in here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server

Add the `onCompletion` and optionally `onCompletionResolve` event handlers as described here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server#_adding-additional-language-features

This is where you could use delegate to the es6 completions.

But you will need to tell VS Code about your language. Your extension needs to contribute that language by adding this section to the `package.json`.

```
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
  {
        "id": "xyz",        
        "extensions": [
          ".xyz"
        ]        
      }
    ],
```

Actually, this is a great article:
https://dzone.com/articles/language-server-protocol-a-language-server-for-dot

Does that help?